# MySQL Query gets too complex for me

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a MYSQL Query that updates a cell in table1 with information gathered from 2 other tables;

The gathering of data from the other 2 tables goes without much issues (it is slow, but that's because one of the 2 tables has 4601537 records in it.. (because all the rows for one report are split in a separate record, meaning that 1 report has more than 200 records)).

The Query that I use to Join the two tables together is:

```
# First Table, containing Report_ID's: RE
# Table that has to be updated: REGI
# Join Table: JT

SELECT JT.report_id as ReportID, REGI.Serienummer as SerialNo FROM Blancco_Registration.TrialTable as REGI
JOIN (SELECT RE.Value_string, RE.report_id 
        FROM Blancco_new.mc_report_Entry as RE
        WHERE RE.path_id=92) AS JT ON JT.Value_string = REGI.Serienummer
WHERE REGI.HardwareType="PC" AND REGI.BlanccoReport=0 LIMIT 100
```

This returns 100 records (I limit it because the database is in use during work hours and I don't want to steal all resources).

However, I want to use these results in a Query that updates the REGI table (which it uses to select the 100 records in the first place). 
However, I get the error that I cannot select from the table itself while updateing it (logically). So I tried selecting the select statement above into a temp table and than Update it; however, then I get the issue that I get to much results (logically! I only need 1 result and get 100) however, I'm getting stuck in my own thougts.. I ultimately need to fill the ReportID into each record of REGI.

I know it should be possible, but I'm no expert in MySQL.. is there anybody that can point me into the right direction?

Ps. fixing the table containing 400k records is not an option, it's a program from an external developer and I can only read that database.

The errors I'm talking about are as follows:

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'TrialTable' for update in FROM clause
```

When I use:

```
UPDATE TrialTable SET TrialTable.BlanccoReport = 
    (SELECT JT.report_id as ReportID, REGI.Serienummer as SerialNo FROM Blancco_Registration.TrialTable as REGI
    JOIN (SELECT RE.Value_string, RE.report_id 
            FROM Blancco_new.mc_report_Entry as RE
            WHERE RE.path_id=92) AS JT ON JT.Value_string = REGI.Serienummer
    WHERE REGI.HardwareType="PC" AND REGI.BlanccoReport=0 LIMIT 100)
     WHERE TrialTable.HardwareType="PC" AND TrialTable.BlanccoReport=0)
```

Then I tried:

```
 UPDATE TrialTable SET TrialTable.BlanccoReport =  (SELECT ReportID  FROM (<<and the rest of the SQL>>> )  as x WHERE X.SerialNo = TrialTable.Serienummer)
```

but that gave me the following error:

```
Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Haveing the Query above with a LIMIT 1, gives everything the same result

Comment: You could at least post the error you are getting from MySQL, and we don't need so much written text.

Comment: The temp table is your best option (and a perfectly valid one). You could also rewrite it to a REPLACE INTO ... SELECT query, which is MySQL dialect. You should, however, check if you have sensible indexes on all tables. Basically everything in a WHERE, ON, and GROUP BY clause is candidate for an index. Also: make a copy of (a sample of) the database and work on a local machine. It makes it much easier to develop things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your query seems to be functionally identical to the following:

```
 SELECT RE.report_id ReportID
      , REGI.Serienummer SerialNo 
   FROM Blancco_Registration.TrialTable REGI
   JOIN Blancco_new.mc_report_Entry RE
     ON RE.Value_string = REGI.Serinummer
  WHERE REGI.HardwareType = "PC" 
    AND REGI.BlanccoReport=0 
    AND RE.path_id=92
  LIMIT 100
```

So, why not use that?

EDIT:
I still don't get it. I can't see what part of the problem the following fails to solve...

```
UPDATE TrialTable REGI
  JOIN Blancco_new.mc_report_Entry RE
    ON RE.Value_string = REGI.Serinummer
   SET TrialTable.BlanccoReport = RE.report_id
 WHERE REGI.HardwareType = "PC" 
   AND REGI.BlanccoReport=0 
   AND RE.path_id=92;
```

Comment: Because I need to update the table with the results of this query, I do however get to much results and need to rewrite the statement to only give back the result that needs to be updated while looping through all records, however... i'm getting confused during trying to write it

Comment: The problem was apparently in my head.. I was thinking too much in brackets and temporary tables..

This does exactly what I needed..

Answer (score 0):

(This is not an answer, but maybe a pointer towards a few points that need further attention)

Your `JT` sub query looks suspicious to me:

```
(SELECT RE.Value_string, RE.report_id 
        FROM Blancco_new.mc_report_Entry as RE
        WHERE RE.path_id=92
        GROUP BY RE.report_id)
```

You use `group by` but don't actually use any aggregate functions. The column `RE.Value_string` should strictly be something like `MAX(RE.Value_string)` instead.

Comment: You're right. the Group BY is a remains of other trials and has no value in this statement, since I'm using the Where statement that only picks the right value, I'll update my question